# how to export error-handling callback-functions in moongoose method into another .js file

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, callback

is there any to way put the error handling callback function in method **find()**
into another module named modules.js. i tried to do so but the only problem is that once the callback function is in another module the res object becomes inaccessible hence i am not able to use res.send method.

```js
app.get('/blogs/all',function(req,res,next){                 
 Blog.find({},function(err,result){
  if(err)
   res.send("some error");
  else
   res.send(result);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can easily do that using [closures](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/).

Now we are going to write a simple function and save it in a file called dbHandler to handle your Db calls.

```
module.exports = function (res) {
  var response = res;
  return function(err,result){
    if(err)
        response.send('some error');
    else
        response.send(result);
  }
};
```

Use this module in your code now.

```
const dbHandler = require('dbHandler');

app.get('/blogs/all',function(req,res,next){    

    Blog.find({},dbHandler(res));

});
```

DBhandler returns a function that acts as callback to your DB call but has access to response due to closure.